# sort nested json on liquid template

Tags: liquid

I have the following json as input for my liquid template

```json
  "Fields": {
        "Field A": {
            "type": "text",
            "value": "foo",
        },
        "Field B": {
            "type": "number",
            "value": 0,
        },
        "Field C": {
            "type": "text",
            "value": "bar",
        },
```

Iterate with `{% for field in Fields %}` works fine and I can access to `field[0]` to get the name or `field[1].value` to get the value.

But is possible to sort the loop?

Something like

```
    {% assign fields_by_name = Fields | sort: "type" %}
    {% for field in fields_by_name %}
```

Works for and array of objects but not for a nested json structure.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your JSON isn't valid, can you post your complete JSON output. If "fields" is an array you can use sort but I can't confirm that because I'm not sure of your actual JSON